# jQuery Show/Hide for <span> and <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="project_id">
    <span title="View Details" class="project_toggle  project_toggle_off" data-task="14"></span>
    <a id="proj_14" class="project_class">Test Project</a>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="task_proj_14" class="task_project_id">Some Hidden Content</div>
```

[image: Test]

**jQuery code to expand/collapse:**

```
//this function is used to toggle project list
        $('.project_toggle').click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.toggleClass('project_toggle_off project_toggle_on');
            $("#task_proj_" + $this.data('task')).slideToggle();
            $this.attr('title', $this.hasClass('project_toggle_off')? 'View Details' : 'Hide Details')
        })
```

**CSS:**

```
.project_toggle_on {
    background: url("../images/minus.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 12px auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.project_toggle_off {
    background: url("../images/plus.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 12px auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

When user Clicks on `PLUS` image, the project expands expands, but how can I make it work when user either clicks on `PLUS` icon OR `Project Name` ? It should not only be the plus icon to expand/collapse the list but both icon and project name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. You can attach event to multiple elements. Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k43znusz/3/).

HTML

```
 <div class="project_id">
   <span title="View Details" class="project_toggle  project_toggle_off" data-task="14"></span>
  <a id="proj_14" class="project_class">Test Project</a>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click','.project_toggle,.project_class',function (event){
   if(event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a'){
       var $this = $(this).parent('div').find('span');
    }else{
       var $this = $(this);
    }

    $this.toggleClass('project_toggle_off project_toggle_on');
    $("#task_proj_" + $this.data('task')).slideToggle();
    $this.attr('title', $this.hasClass('project_toggle_off')? 'View Details' : 'Hide Details')
 });
});
```

Comment: The class has a bgimage attached to it. If that class is applied to `<a>` tag, it spoils the view. The plus icon apears in Project text background

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy  check my updated answer and demo here http://jsfiddle.net/k43znusz/3/

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy  check my fiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/k43znusz/3/  i have apply some code change .. also updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Put the handle on the containing `div` to increase the hit area:

```
<div class="project_id project_toggle project_toggle_off" title="View Details" data-task="14">
    <a id="proj_14" class="project_class">Test Project</a>
</div>
```

```js
$('.project_toggle').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this
        .toggleClass('project_toggle_off project_toggle_on')
        .attr('title', $this.hasClass('project_toggle_off')? 'View Details' : 'Hide Details');
    $("#task_proj_" + $this.data('task')).slideToggle();
})
```

The `span` in the code can also then be removed as it is redundant.

Comment: Rory McCrossan: Pls see CSS update in my question. Also I removed `<span>` and did as you said above, but its still not working when I click on project name.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the click event on the parent div:

HTML:

```
<div class="project_id" class="project_toggle  project_toggle_off" data-task="14">
    <span title="View Details"></span>
    <a id="proj_14" class="project_class">Test Project</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.project_toggle').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('project_toggle_off project_toggle_on');
        $("#task_proj_" + $this.data('task')).slideToggle();
        $this.find('span').attr('title', $this.hasClass('project_toggle_off')? 'View Details' : 'Hide Details')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Html**

```
<div class="project_id">
   <span title="View Details" class="project_toggle  project_toggle_off" data-task="14"></span>
  <a id="proj_14" class="project_class" data-task="14">Test Project</a>
 </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.project_toggle').click(function () {        
        $(this).toggleClass('project_toggle_off project_toggle_on');
        $("#task_proj_" + $(this).data('task')).slideToggle();
        $(this).find('span').attr('title', $(this).hasClass('project_toggle_off')? 'View Details' : 'Hide Details')
});
```

Comment: Developing Developer: It does not expand when I click on `Test Project`.